# How do I Change the view from month to day view if i click on a specific day

Tags: fullcalendar

I am writing a website in html and using full calendar. I got the events to add to the calendar and show.

My question is how do i code the functionality to change the view of the calendar from month to day view  of that day I clicked on when I click on a specific date in month view?

I have this code to give the date i clicked on but cant change the view.

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
    }
});
```